# Embedding Google One-Tap

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

Since Inline Google One-tap Sign Up using YOLO is deprecated (https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline), I tried to integrate One Tap via an Iframe (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe) but my One-Tap still won't showed up.

The best example of embedded Google One-Tap is done by Stytch (https://stytch.com/login) but it's just a third party.

Does anyone have a good idea to implement this?

Thanks in advance.